# How to explore what Visual Studio is doing when it's constantly working in the background?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm updated to Visual Studio 2015 last week, and I'm very disappointed about the performance. In the earlier versions it was also usual that time to time the IDE just hangs and constantly uses CPU about 30%, but in this version it's so often that I'm getting mad of it.

Is there any way to determine what is doing what? I only see `devenv.exe` in the task manager constantly using 30-40% of CPU for almost 30 mins, 3-4 times during a workday. I want to see what is going on. If I could see some details, I would probably be able to disable some feature or extension, etc.

Any tips are appreciated.

UPDATE

My question is kind of general, but just for the record.

- I experience it mostly when I'm editing `TypeScript` files in a large
  `TypeScript` project. But also it happened several times inside a standard C# class library project.
- `TypeScript` compile on save is disabled.
- `TypeScript` version is `1.8.7` or so (latest).
- I have `ReSharper` installed, `Solution-wide analyzis` is turned off.

Comment: Yeh, was annoyed by this happening to me. Found no good solutions.  I had to disable extensions until I narrowed it down.  Was a bunch of analyzers I had installed.  Ripped them back out again and things calmed down.  Another possibility is that you've got tests running in the background.  You can check out the test explorer, or look at the devenv.vstest.exe (?) child process in task manager to see if it's chewing up cycles.

Comment: Start by disabling all extensions (to see if it's the extensions causing the issue) and then adding them one by one. If it is the extensions maybe this will help: [Guide to Speeding Up ReSharper](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=37228482), [ReSharper is slow](https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206546919-Visual-Studio-with-ReSharper-is-slow)

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select "First Level", under  Resource select **CPU usage** and click on **start**. Now capture 1 minute of the CPU usage. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file (+ NGENPDB folder) into 1 zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here or analyze it yourself with WPA: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-42-WPT-CPU-Analysis

Comment: @magicandre1981 thank you for the information, I will give it a try soon and give some feedback about the results.

Comment: were you able to track down the CPU usage?

Comment: @magicandre1981 not yet, actually I don't have any time for a longer tracking process, so I'm just restarting VS in every two hour for now.

Comment: share the zip file if possible (my username {a T ] Ao L (D o T] c O m) and I'll take a look at it