# Visual Studio 2013 with Resharper causes high (100%) CPU

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, cpu

I have been searching for a solution to prevent visual studio causing 100% CPU usage and sending my CPU fan crazy every time I start the application and then intermittently whilst I am using it.

I’m wondering if anyone has another suggestion to what I have already tried
Some details

- Dell Latitude E7440
- Windows 7 OS
- 16gb of Ram
- Intel Core i7-4600U CPU 2.10Ghz Processor
- Visual Studio 2013 (update 5)
- Resharper Ultimate 10

From searching the web and particularly on SO I have tried the following without any luck

- Disable the enable browser link
- Disabled Microsoft Git Provider
- Setting a different intellisense (save to disk disabled)
- Removed web essentials
- Tried in safe mode
- Disabled 'enable rich client visaul experience
- Reset all setting using Import and Export option in Tools

I’m wondering if anyone has another suggestion other than what I have already tried

Thanks

Comment: capture a ETW/WPR trace and share it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36551754/how-to-explore-what-visual-studio-is-doing-when-its-constantly-working-in-the-b#comment60706609_36551754

Comment: You can also go to ReSharper &rarr; Help &rarr; Profile Visual Studio, which will download and attach a profiler, allow you to capture the high CPU, and then zip the trace file up and send it to JetBrains.

Comment: Thank you both I will take a look into these options and get  back